# Javascript else if doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new to this and can not figure out why it doesn't work:

So I have function:

```
function testResults() {
    var answer = document.getElementById("myForm");
    if (answer = 'James'); {
        alert("Good !");
    } else if (answer = 'james'); {
        alert("Good !");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong !");
    }
```

And here is the `<form>`:

```
<form name="myform">
    Enter your name 
    <input type="text" name="inputbox" value="">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Click" onClick="testResults()" >
</form>
```

And it doesn't work.

Comment: Assignment vs comparison, `=` vs `==` vs `===`.

Comment: There are too many issues in your code. I believe you should learn more before proceeding. Here's a great resource: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) PS: You don't need to give a name to every element if you are submitting the form. Just make sure they have a valid ID for easy-selecting. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 bugs in these 2 lines:

```
var answer = document.getElementById("myForm");
if (answer = 'James');
```

The first line retrieves the element with ID `myform` in your page. Since there isn't one, it returns `NULL` and your comparisons always fail.

Once you actually use a correct ID to retrieve the input, you'll still have to get the value instead of the element itself.

Sample:

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="waa">
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('test').value)">Click me!</button>
```

Once you've fixed all that, use `==` for comparisons since `=` is for assignments, and remove the semicolon (`;`) after the `if` since it self-closes the statement.

Comment: And he didn't close his function/

Comment: Yeah well I was just counting the bugs in those 2 lines, but indeed that's a unique 5th bug - the rest of the code is just repeating the same mistakes  :P

Comment: You really need to learn the basics first. The semicolon and `==` issues show that you haven't even mastered the core basics of any kind of programming (that syntax is identical in C#, Java, C++ and PHP). We pointed out all the problems with your code, the only thing we can do more is write it *for you*, which isn't the purpose of Stack Overflow and not at all helpful for you. As @Derek朕會功夫 said: [start here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: @user3163838 - As I commented before, go read the JavaScript guide on MDN and understand how JS works and interacts with DOM before looking in your code again.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form name="myform">
    Enter your name 
    <input type="text" name="inputbox" value="" id="field">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Click" onClick="testResults()" >
</form>


<script>
    function testResults () {
        var answer = document.getElementById("field").value;

        if (answer == 'James')
        {
            alert("Good !");
        }
        else if (answer == 'james')
        {
            alert("Good !");
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Wrong !");
        }
    }
</script>
```

for equal is '==' not single '='

Comment: would still not work. You can't compare a form DOM object to a string.

Comment: oops sorry i didn't see he missing the .value

Comment: ok, it is some kind of working. but not right: No matter what I put it says wrong. So it is going straight to last else. Can you help with that please?

Comment: Just copy and paste the code above (everything), if you type "James" in the input box i should alert "Good" i have just tested

Comment: Super, it works finally...I would give  you vote up but my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/48KLN/2/

```
<form name="myform">
    Enter your name 
    <input type="text" name="inputbox" id='textBox' value=""/>
        <input type="button" name="button" value="Click" onClick="testResults()" />
</form>
        <script>
            function testResults() {
    var answer = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
    if (answer == 'James') {
        alert("Good !");
    } else if (answer == 'james') {
        alert("Good !");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong !");
    }
}
        </script>
```

You did following mistakes

1. You get myForm by id but in html form has only name
2. Even if form would have id you tried to compare HtmlFormObject to string
3. in if you used setter instead of equall
4. after if " (answer = 'James'); " you added ; which is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="numb" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x =0 ;
  x = document.getElementById("numb").value;   
  if ( x < 5 ) {
    text = "Input not valid";
  } else if( x > 5 ) {
    text = "Input OK";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

You've got errors in your code. Let me refine it:

```
function testResults() {
    var answer = document.getElementById("myForm");
    if (answer == 'James'); {
        alert("Good !");
    } else if (answer == 'james'); {
        alert("Good !");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong !");
    }
};
```

Comment: You cannot compare an HTML node to a String.